# If $A-B = B-A$ what can we conclude about A and B?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $A$ and $B$ satisfy $A-B = B-A$. What can we conclude about A and B?

To satisfy $A\setminus B = B\setminus A$ we know that $A \setminus B \subseteq B \setminus A$ and $B \setminus A \subseteq A \setminus B$.
Not sure what to conclude for this information.